# How can I filter a ListView using TextBox and ComboBox?

Tags: vb.net

```
Private Sub ComboBox2_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ComboBox2.SelectedIndexChanged
            ListView2.Items.Clear()
            Dim curSelectionCombobox As String = ComboBox2.SelectedItem.ToString()
            ListView2.Items.Add(listitm)
        End Sub
```

Well basically this is what ive come up with the filtering thing in combobox which is obviously wont work
and in the combobox and button i didnt get to try coding those but im quite sure it wont work either im new in this language and im struggling to catch up giving the fact that this pandemic really gets me more and more stupider as the day passed by

Well my main problem is that the filtering in the groupBox_bookShelf is when i choose a genre in the combobox the static listview will filter leaving only the exact items its genre selected in the combobox

the second is the combobox and button im aiming to link the action of both property when filing in the groupBox_bookInformation then once the filter button is clicked i want to filter the lower listview leaving only the selected genre and its items

Here is the sample form ive been working on.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YwVf2.png)

Comment: Don't use a `ListView` in the first place. Populate a `DataTable`, bind it to a `BindingSource` and bind that to a `DataGridView`. You can then filter the data simply be setting the `Filter` property of the `BindingSource`. You can do the filtering in a dedicated method and call that from the `TextChanged` and `SelectedIndexChanged` event handlers of the `TextBox` and `ComboBox` respectively.

Comment: we were asign to deal with listview and to filter the items stored in it ive also think of using listbox instead but thats the problem profs are hard to understand sometimes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am guessing that what is selected in the combo box is a value that appears in some of your list view items.

Start by calling `.BeginUpdate()` This will prevent the user interface from repainting on each update which would really slow things down.

I loop through the items and test one of the sub items to see if it matches the combo selection. If it does not match is is removed.

Be sure to call `.EndUpdate` or the changes will not show up.

```
Private Sub ComboBox2_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ComboBox2.SelectedIndexChanged
    Dim curSelectionCombobox As String = ComboBox2.SelectedItem.ToString()
    ListView2.BeginUpdate()
    For Each lvi As ListViewItem In ListView2.Items
        If lvi.SubItems(6).Text <> curSelectionCombobox Then
            lvi.Remove()
        End If
    Next
    ListView2.EndUpdate()
End Sub
```

Comment: Sorry for the late reply maam it works like a charm! i really appreciate your work but it seems it has a flaw when i try to reselect a genre in the combobox all the items in the listview somewhat disappear. but im glad it works at the first try

Comment: Yes, you will have to refill your ListView with the original data before you can apply other filters. I am guessing you already have the code where you first filled it. If it is in an event procedure then move it to a separate Sub that you can call from anywhere.